# Calculating slide index after ad offset

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sequence

I've rigged up a simple JS gallery to implement "deep linking" allowing a URL with a hash like `#slide-3` to automatically load the gallery with the third slide active. There's an ad in the gallery every seventh slide. These ad slides aren't tracked so the hash becomes `#slide-x` followed by an image slide, i.e. `#slide-7`.]

I've created a helper function to convert the slide numbers from the hash into the 0-indexed slide number, taking into account these ads every seventh slide, but was curious if anyone could think of a more graceful way to calculate the proper index as my implementation looks way too complicated to my eye:

```
var slideNum = parseInt( window.location.hash.replace( '#slide-', '' ), 10 );
slideNum += Math.floor( ( slideNum + Math.floor( slideNum / 7 ) ) / 7 ) - 1;
return slideNum;
```

That works but having two floors seems like overkill. There must be a simpler way! I'm not sure of the algebraic rules that govern the floor operation however so I can't figure out how to expand/simplify myself. Any help would be appreciated.

I've included a basic JS fiddle which outputs values for the first 36 slides compared to their proper values. Feel free to change the `testFunc` with your solution and see if works!

```js
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36];

var correct = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,25,26,28,29,30,31,32,33,35,36,37,38,39,40];

var testFunc = function( n ) {
    var offset = ( n + Math.floor( n / 7 ) ) / 7;
    return n + Math.floor( offset ) - 1;  
};

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += 'Input Expected Output<br/>';
for( var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += nums[i] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + correct[i] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + testFunc( nums[i] ) + '<br/>';
    if ( ( i + 1 ) % 6 === 0 ) {
         document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += 'AD<br/>';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one integer division is enough:

```
var testFunc = function( n ) {
    n = n - 1;
    return Math.floor(n / 6) + n
};
```

Comment: D'oh of course! Massive brain fart for some reason. The 7 or 6 thing was throwing me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Realized we have both indices on each slide element so I can simply select using the URL index and get the true slide index from the DOM. Still a fun problem to think about perhaps!?